# Change the style of a grid row when checkcolumn is checked in Extjs4

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a grid with a checkcolumn.  I want to be able to change the style of a given row of checkbox on that row is checked.

Right now I have this:

```
listeners: {
    checkchange: function (checkcolumn, rowIndex, checked) {
        if (checked) {
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't know what to put inside the conditional that will give me an object with a method that allows me to change the style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override the [getRowClass](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.view.Table-method-getRowClass) method. When the checkbox changes, the row will update in the DOM which will trigger this method.